# Lay a Textview over an Imageview while the Imageview uses layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

I got 4 Imageviews in a Tablerow. They are scaled through the `layout_weight` command. I need to write in this Imageviews now. Is there any possibility to do this without having to use `alignparent` meaning using a relative layout?

This is my code at the Moment:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.2f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2.4f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 3.6f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params4 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 4.8f);


        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(params);



        ImageView rank = new ImageView(this);
        rank.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        rank.setLayoutParams(params1);
        rank.setImageResource(R.drawable.whitebutton);

        Layout[i] = new ImageView(this);
        Layout[i].setLayoutParams(params2);
        Layout[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.width2);
        Layout[i].setAdjustViewBounds(true);

        Layout[i+10] = new ImageView(this);
        Layout[i+10].setLayoutParams(params3);
        Layout[i+10].setImageResource(R.drawable.width3);
        Layout[i+10].setAdjustViewBounds(true);


        Layout[i+20] = new ImageView(this);
        Layout[i+20].setLayoutParams(params4);
        Layout[i+20].setImageResource(R.drawable.width4);
        Layout[i+20].setAdjustViewBounds(true);


        tableRow.addView(rank);
        tableRow.addView(Layout[i]);
        tableRow.addView(Layout[i+10]);
        tableRow.addView(Layout[i+20]);
        t.addView(tableRow);
```

This is the Interface I want to create:
[image: interface]

well, in addition the same sized 4 pictures with the actual highscore in it

Answer (score 0):

use a `TextView` instead of `ImageView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:text="hai every one !"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#EF5350"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:drawableBottom="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

here you can use the Text, Background as well as 4 drawables.You can arrange the drawables using the paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight and paddingBottom.

oR

use `RelativeLayout` instead of `ImageView`.Add the  `TextView` inside the `RelativeLayout`

i prefer the first approach.

Comment: but in this case i lose the weight command which is necessary